# Irrelevant interactions and vacuum configurations

Tags: vacuum, effective-field-theory, semiclassical

I am confused about some aspects of irrelevant interactions and vacua in effective field theories.
For definiteness lets focus on a theory which can be described semiclassically at low energies and then start adding some irrelevant interactions to the Lagrangian.
The standard lore about irrelevant interactions is roughly speaking that diagrams involving irrelevant vertices give higher powers in the external momenta than the diagrams without irrelevant vertices. Hence correlation functions of operators converge to the values that they would have in the theory without any irrelevant interactions in the low energy limit.

On the other hand, say that the theory contains a scalar field $\phi$. In the theory without irrelevant interactions it will obtain some vacuum expectation value $\langle \phi\rangle$. However one may then add irrelevant terms of the form $\sum c_n \phi^n$ to the Lagrangian ($n$ is supposed to be big enough for $ \phi^n$ to have mass dimension larger than $d$, the dimension of spacetime). The $c_n$ then contain a mass scale, and the new classical potential $V(\phi)$ has (depending on the coefficients $c_n$) potentially a very different set of minima than the potential before adding the irrelevant terms. Classically these irrelevant interactions are much more important than the relevant ones at higher values of $ \phi$ . If one now tries to compute a correlation function, one should first find a suitable classical vacuum and then do perturbation theory around it. However now due to the presence of these new terms in the Lagrangian, the classical vacuum could be shifted immensly, say to very large $\phi$, which has potentially very different physics than the original vacuum. So in that case the standard lore that irrelevant terms don't change low energy physics very much would not be true.
One potential way out would be to demand, that the $c_n$ all come with higher orders of $\hbar$, but I don't know if that is sensible.
Is the reasoning above wrong?

I want to give 2 examples, where irrelevant terms are seemingly treated differently.

On the one hand one has the Standard model, which contains the Higgs and one can add irrelevant interactions. Here one views irrelevant terms just as new vertices, but one doesn't let them influence the classical vacuum. They are seemingly ignored when computing the classical background solution (in which the Higgs obtains a VeV).

On the other hand for example, when one wants to look at say supergravity in 10 dimensions, one cares very much for the irrelevant interaction terms already at the classical level, since then one can look at interesting background spacetimes such as $AdS$ or black holes, that satisfy Einsteins equations or related stringy equations.

So which of these two different ways of practicing effective field theory is right?
What is the correct way to think about these issues?

Answer (score 0):

To zeroth order, you would only trust the effective field theory to give you reliable results when the background field and its derivatives were much less than the cutoff. Let's say you added a few higher dimension operators to the Standard Model, which created a new minimum in the Higgs potential. This minimum would necessarily involve a large ratio of $H/M$, where $H$ was the Higgs vev and $M$ was the cutoff scale. (Otherwise, the higher dimension operators would be dominated by the lower order terms in the potential). The question would then be, how do you know that only the higher dimension operators you included were important, and not the other possible operators at even higher dimension? Furthermore, the full quantum action has an infinite tower of higher derivative terms as well; how do you know these aren't important?

I'm not an expert on supergravity by any means, but from what I understand the situation there is a little different, since symmetry considerations constrain the form of the quantum corrections such that you have some control.

Having said that, people do try to argue in some cases that so long as the derivatives of the field are small, it is not a problem to have a potential where the value of the field is larger than the cutoff. This situation arises in inflationary theory due to the Lyth bound (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9606387), which roughly speaking says that (in simple models of inflation) the inflaton must have rolled a distance larger than the Planck mass down its potential. I think this gets into fairly murky and controversial territory pretty quickly.